# Using `glm()` in R for correlated count data (data provided)

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, count-data, discrete-data

I have data from one group ($n = 25$) of subjects pre- and post- tested on an $15$-item dichotomously scored test (see below).

Given that the data are from the same subjects (i.e., correlated), how can I correctly use ***count regression*** to compare the performance of the group at the two testing points (i.e., pre and post)?

I appreciate an `R` demonstration.

Here is what I have done (ignoring the correlated data) in `R`:

```
pre = c(9,10,8,9,6,7,9,7,8,6,8,4,8,11,6,7,9,9,6,6,9,9,10,9,8)

post = c(13,10,10,12,9,11,12,9,7,9,7,3,7,9,6,10,10,12,8,9,8,9,10,10,7)


y <- c(pre, post) 
group <- rep(0:1, each = 25)
summary(model <- glm(cbind(y, 15 - y) ~ group, binomial) )
```

Comment: The fact that they are correlated with cause a problem for glm. glmer in the lme4 package can probably handle something like this

Comment: @TPM that’s not necessary. I think first we need to understand what OP is trying to understand from their data. What exactly is the research question and hypothesis.

Comment: @Jon, I want to compare the proportion of success between the two testing points?

Comment: @rnorouzian if all you want to do is compare two groups (means/proportions) with correlated observations you can either use a Wilcoxon Signed Rank test (as shown by @Noah) or a Paired T-Test. Using a GLM complicates the situation, mostly because you're doing more work than is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't what's typically meant by "count data" in statistics.  When statisticians talk about count data, they are referring to non-negative whole numbers that have no upper limit ($[0, \infty)$).  Your data are bounded counts (counts out of a finite total).  They are binomial data.  These would typically be modeled with logistic regression (or probit, etc.), not "count regression", which typically implies Poisson or negative binomial regression.

The next issue is that you have repeated measures, which means the data are not independent.  The proposed model treats the data as independent—that will lead to incorrect standard errors, p-values, etc.

There are several ways to model data like these.  The most common would probably be to use a GLMM to model scores as a function of time:

```
library(lme4)                # we'll need this package
y     = c(pre, post) 
time  = rep(0:1, each = 25)
id    = rep(1:25, times=2)   # we need an indicator for the participants
model = glmer(cbind(y, 15-y)~time+(1|id), family=binomial)  # this fits the GLMM
summary(model, correlation=FALSE)
# Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace
#   Approximation) [glmerMod]
#  Family: binomial  ( logit )
# Formula: cbind(y, 15 - y) ~ time + (1 | id)
# 
#      AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
#    209.4    215.2   -101.7    203.4       47 
# 
# Scaled residuals: 
#     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
# -2.2694 -0.5616  0.1626  0.3804  1.6842 
# 
# Random effects:
#  Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
#  id     (Intercept) 0.07019  0.2649  
# Number of obs: 50, groups:  id, 25
# 
# Fixed effects:
#             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
# (Intercept)   0.1138     0.1170   0.973   0.3307  
# time          0.3211     0.1492   2.152   0.0314 *
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: Thank you! Just a quick comment, *conceptually* how the pre-post correlation can be accounted for here? I suppose you mean by assuming that `p` from the binomial response distribution from each `time` is *controlled* by a hyper binomial distribution at a higher level? But how this could account for correlation?

Comment: @rnorouzian, this is a generalized linear mixed effects model.  There is a random intercept assigned to each participant `+(1|id)`. It may help you to read about [tag:mixed-model]s & [tag:glmm]s.

Comment: I will but my question is not so much statistical. Random intercept means that we assume participant have had different starting place at the pre-testing time. So, we expect some variation within the individual intercepts (which are deviations from the average intercept). My problem is how your analysis related to a common picture of multi-level models [*like this*](https://bookdown.org/MathiasHarrer/Doing_Meta_Analysis_in_R/mlma.html) and how correlation is shown there.

Comment: @rnorouzian, random effects in a mixed model is similar but not quite the same as a 'random effects model' in meta-analysis.  (Economists, in turn, mean a 3rd thing by 'random effects model'.)  It is unfortunate that these terms are used in different ways in different areas.

Comment: @rnorouzian, you can if you want. There is a lot of material on the site now, so you should read around some to make sure what you're asking isn't already covered.

Comment: Dear gung, [here is my question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/475279/how-multi-level-model-account-for-correlation-and-what-kinds-of-correlations)?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the Wilcoxon signed-rank test, which is essentially a non-parametric version of the paired t-test. In R, you would run

```
wilcox.test(pre, post, paired=TRUE)
```

You could also run a paired t-test (ignoring the count nature of the data) using `t.test()`, which will yield the same conclusion (although in this case, the non-normality of the difference scores and the small sample size might steer you away from this method).