# How multi-level models account for correlation and what kinds of correlations?

Tags: r, regression, multilevel-analysis

Multi-level models are often shown using figures such as below. These pictures say that observed data at the lowest level (BLUE TRIANGLES) come from some independent populations (BLUE CURVES). But the parameters of these independent populations ($\theta$s), themselves, come from a higher-order population of parameters (GREEN CURVE).

Say I have ~ $7000$ math scores from 160 schools. Here, the scores are the BLUE TRIANGLES assumed to have come from their independent school-level population scores.

At the same time, the $\theta$s of these independent school-level population scores is assumed have come from a higher-order population of $\theta$s.

**Question:** I can see that schools' $\theta$s is a random effect BUT what kind of correlation (between what?) are we accounting for in this picture?

[image: FIGURE 1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multi-level models of this type are accounting for *positive* correlation among observations within a group (i.e. among students within a school).  We can work this out as follows:

- let's say that $x_{ij}$ is the observation for the $j$th student in the $i$th school
- according to the statistical model, $x_{ij} = \mu + \epsilon_{b,i} + \epsilon_{w,j}$ where $b$ stands for "between" (school-level variance) and $w$ stands for "within" (student-level variance)
- the correlation between any two observations is equal to $\sigma_{ij,kl}/(\sigma_{ij} \sigma_{kl})$
- $\sigma_{ij}$ is the same for all observations: $\sigma_{ij}^2= E[(x_{ij}-\mu)^2] = E[\epsilon_{b,i}^2 + 2 \epsilon_{b,i} \epsilon_{w,j} + \epsilon_{w,j}^2]$. Because all of the $\epsilon$ are independent by definition, the middle term disappears and we're left with $\sigma_{ij} = \sqrt{\sigma^2_w+\sigma^2_b}$.
- if $i\neq k$ (i.e. we're looking at students in two different schools) then the covariance $\sigma_{ij,kl}=0$: when we expand out $E[(\epsilon_{b,i} + \epsilon_{w,j})(\epsilon_{b,k} + \epsilon_{w,l})]$ we end up with the sum of expectations of products of independent variables ...
- if $i=k$ (e.g. $\sigma_{ij,il}$) then we have $E[(\epsilon_{b,i} + \epsilon_{w,j})(\epsilon_{b,i} + \epsilon_{w,l})]$; the only term that's left after we expand and cancel is $E[\epsilon_{b,i}^2] = \sigma^2_b$.

So after all this we have a correlation of 0 for students in different schools, and correlation of $\sigma^2_b/(\sigma^2_b + \sigma^2_w)$  for students in the same school. As the between-school variance goes to 0 (i.e. all schools are really identical in their characteristics), correlation goes to 0. As $\sigma^2_b$ gets large relative to $\sigma^2_w$ (there's a lot more difference between schools than between students within a school), correlation goes to 1.

Comment: Ben, thank you so much. By correlation between any two students within a school, you mean the correlation that could arise in the long-run, if we repeat our experiment ad infinitum, right?

Comment: Some of the other things I had in mind: compound-symmetry models (where uniform negative as well as positive correlations within groups could be represented); random-slopes models (where we model correlation between slopes and intercepts as well as correlation among observations within a group)

Comment: Awesome! how about correlations in crossed (cross-classified) designs?

Comment: Those could presumably be derived following the same general derivation as I gave above (for any two observations, it's the ratio of the variance they share to the total variance).

Comment: yes, I think so (I don't ever use that phrase exactly, but $\sigma^2_b$ is the variance of the distribution of $\theta$.

Comment: Dear Ben, I'm not a math person but curious about one thing since you used $E()$ and other frequentist notations in your answer. When you say: *"the correlation of students in the same school is `σ2b/(σ2b+σ2w)`"*, does that mean, that, if we infinitely repeat ($1,...n$) the same data collection procedure from the same $j$ schools, then, the correlation between students' scores within the same school (ex. $j=1$) from any two iterations (ex. $n=1$ and $n=2$) is statistically estimated by `σ2b/(σ2b+σ2w)`?